# Extracting a version of a List in Sharepoint based on date

Tags: sharepoint

I wonder if anyone is aware of a way of extracting a list in Sharepoint based on a version's date.

For example, we have a list and over time different people are editing and adding records.

Say we want to see the list's contents on a particular day, so that newer items and recent edits are excluded. In other words view the list "snap shoted" at a particular date.

Is that possible is Sharepoint, or does that type of query need to be done via some code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible via the GUI afaik; filtering in views cannot be applied against versions. I think your best bet is via code.

Comment: I agree with this, but as far as I can imagine, the code will be VERY ineffective, unless you use some extra data structures for storing the versions that are easy to read from.